# getting json value as the key when fetching

Tags: node.js, json, express, post, fetch

I'm not sure why this happens but I keep getting my input value as a key inside of my json object when I send it via fetch POST

sending from client

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        //show the modal when dom is ready
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    });

    async function postData(url = '',data) {

  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default , no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

    document.getElementById("loginButton").addEventListener('click',function(){
      console.log('sending data',document.getElementById("passholder").value)
        postData(`http://${window.location.hostname}:3000/authenticate`, {password: document.getElementById("passholder").value} )      
            .then(() => {console.log('returned from server') });
    })
</script>
```

index js route in express

```
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)

});
```

what I get logged

```
{ '{"password":"myinputvalue"}': '' }
```

I know this value is already JSON so I can't parse it, does anyone know how to extract the value from the key. clearly I can't do req.body.password..... is there some way to do req.body.child.value?? any info would be amazing, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.keys(req.body)` to get the key. i.e. `'{"password":"myinputvalue"}'`.

Then use `JSON.parse()` to parse the key to JSON.

Then simply use the `.` operator on parsed JSON object to get `password`.

---

```
const key = Object.keys(req.body)[0];
const parsedKey = JSON.parse(key);
const password = parsedKey.password;
```

Comment: yep! that worked for me :) thank you very much! I've been dealing with this annoying thing for a few hours trying to find a solution. Do you happen to know why I can't parse the value of the initial object outright? I'm just curious.

Comment: @monsterpiece,  I didn't understand which object you are talking about. But if you are talking about `{ '{"password":"myinputvalue"}': '' }`  , then  you are trying to parse a JSON to convert it into JSON. That won't work.